# Computer overriding autorun behaviour of CD?

Tags: autorun

I'm hoping this isnt too much of a problem, but I want to make sure.
I'm creating an autorun CD that when put in, will launch a Flash Video with links for customers to navigate through.
I've created my autorun.inf file in the root directory of the CD with the following info in it:

```
 [autorun]
 open=catmenu.exe
```

However, when I try and run the file on an other computer I still get the options screen 'run program or open to view files'. If I click 'run program' then it launches like normal. I think this is just the computer overiding the autorun feature, but I've never made a CD before so I cant be sure. Is there a way to bypass this 'run or view' option or is that just the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autorun is determined by the operating system. For Windows 7 as an example - you can go to the Control Panel | AutoPlay and change the settings for each type of media (software, music, video). It is generally safest to work with the "Ask me" option or "Take no action"